# Eliminate double quotes generated by ','.join() call

Tags: python, list, dictionary

List_final is a global variable that I am building to push the data to a csv format.

key_values in the below code returns the result in a double quotes.So my final list has a double quotes that I am trying to remove.

```
for entry,value_all in csv_data.iteritems():

        list_temp=[entry]
        key_values = ','.join(value_all.itervalues())    
        str(key_values).replace('"', '')

        list_temp.append(str(key_values))
        list_final.append(list_temp) 

with open('test.csv', 'w') as fp:
        writer = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
        writer.writerows(list_final)
```

output:

```
2018-01-27T08:00:00.000Z,"11,14,16,65,234,7,7,574"
2018-01-28T08:00:00.000Z,"1095,141,1646,638,2360,6,6,576"
```

Comment: That's not because of the `join` call itself, but the fact that otherwise you would see the values as separate ones. A row like `1, 4, 2, 5` would be interpreted a four different values, whereas `1, "4, 2", 5` as three with one string that has a comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes are *not* introduced by the `','.join` itself. The point is that the CSV writer sees a string with a comma, and thus decides to escape the string and wrap it into quotes.

But based on the sample output, I think you want the data to show up as separate columns. The idea of using a CSV writer is that you do *not* have to do the string construction yourself. In case you want to write it as separate values, you can use:

```
for entry,value_all in csv_data.iteritems():
        list_temp=[entry]
        list_temp += value_all.itervalues()
        list_final.append(list_temp) 

with open('test.csv', 'w') as fp:
        writer = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
        writer.writerows(list_final)
```

Or we can use list comprehension:

```
list_final = [[entry, *value_all.itervalues()]
              for entry,value_all in csv_data.iteritems()]

with open('test.csv', 'w') as fp:
        writer = csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
        writer.writerows(list_final)
```